# How can i include loop for these nodes in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have these value in php

```
<?php $phpArray = array(
      0 => "Mon", 
      1 => "Tue", 
      2 => "Wed", 
      3 => "Thu",
      4 => "Fri", 
      5 => "Sat",
      6 => "Sun",
      );
?>
```

I get these values in a loop like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var jArray= <?php echo json_encode($phpArray ); ?>;

for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
   // alert(jArray[i]);
}

 </script>
```

But I have a situation like this where I need loop

```
{ data: { id: 'e', name: 'store', weight: 45, faveColor: '#EDA1ED', faveShape: 'ellipse'     } },
```

Now i want that value on 'Store' and remains I want same ,I want to fetch all data through loop.
How can i do this ?????

Comment: It is kind of multi dimensional array where in you have to loop throught. `echo $array['data']['name']` should do it..

Comment: what should the result array look like? - and can anybody improve that english for me. I am no native speaker so it's hard for me to catch the clue here ...

Answer (score 0):

Thats relative easy:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var jArray= []; 

<? foreach($phpArray as $item): ?>
jArray.push("<?=$item?>");
<?endforeach;?>
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry iam a beginner so i need more deyails, i want to get that php data in a loop at here >> name: 'store'  which has more data around it so how can i get loop on that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$phpArray = array(
      "id" => "e", 
      "name" => "Store", 
      "weight" => 45, 
      "faveColor" => "#EDA1ED", 
      "faveShape" => "ellipse"
);

$arr_data['data'] = $phpArray

?>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    var str = '<?php echo stripslashes(json_encode($arr_data));?>';
    alert(str); // output: {"data":{"id":"e","name":"Store","weight":45,"faveColor":"#EDA1ED","faveShape":"ellipse"}}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
<script>
    var jstring = {'data': { 'id': 'e', 'name': 'store', 'weight': 45, 'faveColor': '#EDA1ED', 'faveShape': 'ellipse'}};
    for (key in jstring.data){
        alert("key : " + key + " => " + "Value : " + jstring.data[key])
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Look i need that php values on 'store' likes withoutloop i can do it like name: jArray[0] it display mon, now i want a loop that it display all data from php array.(Sorry for my bad english and low knowledge)

Comment: I didnt understood what actually you want :( so you don't want a loop ?